# Upload files with AJAX - xhr

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to upload files with AJAX but my output is always empty...

so what's wrong or what's missing from the code ? thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

**JS:**

```
$(":file").bind('change blur', function(e) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    name = file.name;
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(size);
    /**
        OUTPUT:
            2-years-anniversaryv1.png jquery.form.img.js:10
            18407 
    */
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false); 
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
            console.log($.ajaxSettings.xhr().upload);
            alert(result);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});

function progress(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
private function upload_file() {

   $this->getLog(print_r($_FILES,true));

   $returnData = array("file" => 'asd');

   echo json_encode($returnData);

}
```

**getLog output:**

```
Array
(
)

Array
(
)

Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you upload through AJAX, you'll need to access the file's content using `fopen()`:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('php://input','rb');
$target = fopen('file_name_here','wb');
while($chunk=fread($f,8192)){
    fwrite($target,$chunk);
}
fclose($f);
fclose($target);
```

Also, you'll need to read the file's content using the `FileReader` class:

```
var file = this.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(){
        //upload finished
    }
    xhr.open('POST','path/to/upload.php',true);
    xhr.send(e.target.result);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Comment: That's a bit lengthy... what's wrong with `copy("php://input","file_name_here")`?

Comment: Well… I'm not so sure if PHP input stream can be copied just like a file.

Comment: I wouldn't have suggested it if I hadn't tried it first :p It works just fine.