# PHP is only passing FILE name to my script

Tags: php

I am working on building some AJAX video upload functionaliyy on my CMS, and ended up implementing the solution which was awarded the bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) as it best suited my purposes (cross browser compatibility isn't an issue as I will only ever be managing my site via Chrome).

I've been experiencing some extremely strange behavior when I submit my form, when I var dump - the contents of my $_FILES array only includes the name parameter

[image]

The jQuery I use to submit to my upload file is as follows:

```
$('#confirm').click(function(){
var file = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: './app/core/commands/upload.php',  
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    //Ajax events
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    // Form data

    data: file,
    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

});

Any ideas as to why my $_FILE array is empty??  I am baffled.

Comment: You can't upload using ajax, you need some iframe trick

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14662614/ and I quote - *"If you upload through AJAX, you'll need to access the file's content using [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)"*

Comment: You're welcome Alex.